# Add class name for selected radio button div

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parent-child, addclass

```
<div>
    One : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof1-grey" value="grey" />
    Two : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof2-pink" value="pink" />
    Three : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof3-green" value="green" />   
<div>
<div id="one" style="display:none;">
    ABC : <input type="text" name="abc" value="" />
    PQR : <input type="text" name="pqr" value="" />
</div>
<div id="two" style="display:none;">
    XYZ : <input type="text" name="xyz" value="" />
</div>
<div id="three" style="display:none;">
    Full Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="" />
</div>
```

If select "One"(Grey) radio button, i need to show DIV id "one" and add class name(required) to all input fields with in the div.
The same way if i change to pink radio button remove the previous div class name and add into the DIV id two using Jquery.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

You can relate the radio controls to the `div` by their `index`. You can then add/remove the classes as needed. Try this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').removeClass('required');
    $('div').not(':first').hide();
    $('div').eq($(this).index() + 1).show().find('input').addClass('required');
});
```

Note that you can simplify this logic by the use of classes in your HTML:

```
<div>
    One : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof1-grey" class="radio" value="grey" />
    Two : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof2-pink" class="radio" value="pink" />
    Three : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof3-green" class="radio" value="green" />   
<div>
<div id="one" class="optional-div">
    ABC : <input type="text" name="abc" value="" class="text-input" />
    PQR : <input type="text" name="pqr" value="" class="text-input" />
</div>
<div id="two" class="optional-div">
    XYZ : <input type="text" name="xyz" value="" class="text-input" />
</div>
<div id="three" class="optional-div">
    Full Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="" class="text-input" />
</div>
```

```js
$('.radio').change(function() {
    $('.text-input').removeClass('required');
    $('.optional-div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show().find('.text-input').addClass('required');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jyxoteLa/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, I added a class sub to every div element which has to show/hide when a radiobutton is clicked.

```js
var divs = ['#one', '#two', '#three'];
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var current = $(divs[$(this).index()]);
    $('.sub').hide();
    $('input').removeClass('required');
    current.show();
    current.children('input').addClass('required');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    One : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof1-grey" value="grey" />
    Two : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof2-pink" value="pink" />
    Three : <input type="radio" name="typeof" id="typeof3-green" value="green" />   
<div>
<div id="one" class="sub" style="display:none;">
    ABC : <input type="text" name="abc" value="" />
    PQR : <input type="text" name="pqr" value="" />
</div>
<div id="two" class="sub" style="display:none;">
    XYZ : <input type="text" name="xyz" value="" />
</div>
<div id="three" class="sub" style="display:none;">
    Full Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="" />
</div>
```

The only thing that you have to do is add the classname to the divs array when you make a fourth option. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ??

**html**

```
<div>
    One : <input type="radio" name="typeof" data-target="#one" class="radiobtn" value="grey" />
    Two : <input type="radio" name="typeof" data-target="#two" class="radiobtn" value="pink" />
    Three : <input type="radio" name="typeof" data-target="#three" class="radiobtn" value="green" />   
<div>
<div class="toTarget" id="one" >
    ABC : <input type="text" name="abc" value="" />
    PQR : <input type="text" name="pqr" value="" />
</div>
<div class="toTarget" id="two" >
    XYZ : <input type="text" name="xyz" value="" />
</div>
<div class="toTarget" id="three" >
    Full Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.toTarget{
  display:none;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$('.radiobtn').click(function(){
var color = $(this).val();
var Thistarget = $(this).attr('data-target');
$('.toTarget').css('display','none');
$(Thistarget+' input').attr('required');
$(Thistarget).css({
'display':'block'
});
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/epu0osxz/1/)